# Can a jointer or a thicknesser be used as a drum sander?

Tags: sanding, thickness-planer, sander

A thicknesser works by rotating a drum with knives to remove material from a board with one flat edge. The board is fed against the drum by a conveyor belt or by an infeed roller as shown in this image:

[image]

**Is there something stopping me from removing the knives, wrapping the drum in sandpaper and using this machine as a drum sander?**

The obvious thing that comes to mind is the *speed at which the drum rotates*. For instance, my thicknesser has a fixed speed of **4000 rpm**, which is too high for a drum sander with the same drum diameter (shouldn't be above **2000 rpm**).

Is there anything else? I guess there must be a fundamental hindrance somewhere in the idea, otherwise, we would see many sander-thicknessers on the market. Lamentably, there are no such machines.

Comment: Interesting notion. Do you have an idea of how you might clamp the sandpaper?

Comment: The interior isn't made to handle loose grit, I'm sure you'd soon ruin your much-more-highly-engineered thicknesser if you did this much, assuming you could run it slowly enough. Coming at this another way, can you not see a way/ways you could avoid having to have a drum sander? While they certainly have uses, they're hardly ubiquitous, even in workshops built entirely around power tools.....

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate I would try double-sided tape or stick-on velcro.